# How to fetch the Rowid with all the columns of a table using bulk collect for a cursor in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, bulk-collect

```
declare
    cursor c_1 is select a.*, a.rowid from an_test a;

    type t_1 is table of an_test%rowtype;

    type l_row_id is table of UROWID;

    tab t_1; 

    row l_row_id;

begin
    open c_1;

    loop
        fetch c_1 bulk collect into tab, row limit 1000;
        ...
    end loop;
end;
```

I am trying to execute the above code but it is giving me the error like :

> PLS-00597: expression 'tab' in the INTO list is of wrong type.

Is there any other/alternate way to do like this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can manage with the rowid in the same record, base your type on the cursor instead of the table:

```
declare
    cursor c is
        select a.*, a.rowid
        from   customer a;

    type t is table of c%rowtype;
    tab t;

begin
    open c;
    fetch c bulk collect into tab limit 1000;
end;
```

Comment: Yeah it helped me, Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Should be something like this:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL> declare
  2    cursor c1 is select d.*, d.rowid from dept d;
  3    type t1r is record
  4      (deptno   number,
  5       dname    varchar2(20),
  6       loc      varchar2(20),
  7       rowid    urowid
  8      );
  9    type t1t is table of t1r;
 10    t1   t1t;
 11  begin
 12    open c1;
 13    fetch c1 bulk collect into t1;
 14    close c1;
 15
 16    for i in t1.first .. t1.last loop
 17      dbms_output.put_line(rpad(t1(i).dname, 15, ' ') ||' '|| t1(i).rowid);
 18    end loop;
 19  end;
 20  /
ACCOUNTING      AAAGvqAAEAAAAIUAAA
RESEARCH        AAAGvqAAEAAAAIUAAB
SALES           AAAGvqAAEAAAAIUAAC
OPERATIONS      AAAGvqAAEAAAAIUAAD

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need extra variable for rowid in this case. Just remove `, row`  from
`fetch c_1 bulk collect into tab, row limit 1000;`

It should be simple
`fetch c_1 bulk collect into tab limit 1000;`

Comment: but i need rowid from the table for deletion purpose.

Answer (score 0):

```
SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL> declare
       cursor c1 is select d.*, d.rowid from dept d;
       type t1r is record
         (deptno   number,

              dname    varchar2(20),

          loc      varchar2(20),
          rowid    urowid
         );
       type t1t is table of t1r;
       t1   t1t;
     begin
       open c1;
       fetch c1 bulk collect into t1;
       close c1;
   
       for i in t1.first .. t1.last loop
         dbms_output.put_line(rpad(t1(i).dname, 15, ' ') ||' '|| t1(i).rowid);
       end loop;
   end;
   /
```

Comment: Please don't add the row numbers.